# The custom connector property 'capabilities' cannot be updated - PowerApps

Tags: powerapps

While updating the connector in powerapps, I am getting this error : "The custom connector property 'capabilities' cannot be updated".

please find the screenshot.
[image]

Comment: I have the same issue today. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I have the same issue unfortunately.

Comment: Stack Overflow needs a Me Too button, because, well, Me too! :-(

Comment: Anyway, clearly this is a bug. One work around is to download the connector, edit it using a text editor, delete the one on the server and then import it back in. It sucks but it's the only way I managed to do it.

Comment: @GlaucusI agree. I will contact the product team about this.